# Redirect header function to replace a poll "thank you" page already in place with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, function, header

I have a PHP Poll already in place, but I've set it up to have multiple (10), after each Poll submission instead of it saying "Thank You, blah blah"... I am wanting to go right to the next Poll questions.

This is what I have.

The poll already has a functionality that on the "Thank You" page has a "Continue to Next Poll" button, I want to remove this button and page and have it just go right to the poll automatically. The best way I could think of this was to just forward with the header.

Example of the button that is already in place that forwards to next poll:

```
 <a href="<?php the_return_to_url(); ?>">Next</a>
```

So if some one could help me convert that to be used with this:

```
 <?php 
 header('Location: http://');
 ?>
```

The "the_return_to_url()" determines what poll it was on and goes up 1.

Here is that function:

```
function the_return_to_url() {
global $requested_poll_id;
global $VALID_POLLS;
$poll = $VALID_POLLS[$requested_poll_id];

if(!empty($poll->returnToURL)) {
    echo $poll->returnToURL;
} else {
    vote_die("ERROR: Return to URL not defined for this poll.");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modification of the original function:

```
<?php
ob_start();
the_return_to_url();
header('Location: http://'.ob_get_clean());
die();
?>
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much.   I was trying veriations like header('Location: the_return_to_url()); and such